# How to Revoke / Cancel / Unregister "Location Services" inside of the iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to revoke the Location Services within an iPhone app?
I would like to change the `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` from `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` to `kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied` or `kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted`, like we can do with the Notifications status, calling: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]` is a read-only method. That is something a user sets, that is beyond the control of your app.

What you should be doing is stopping the `CLLocationManager` from updating if you are finished with it. Create a property or iVar for location manager, then when you no longer need updates just call:

`[myLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation];`

You can also check the authorisation status before starting location updates like so:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // start updating location
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I did something like this. Pretty sad that I can't just unregister the app for location services, just like Push Notifications. I have to handle the user preferences by myself. Anyway, thanks for the time to answer my question.

Comment: I can't really see the need for such a method. You should check the authorisation status before telling `CLLocationManager` to start updating. See my updating answer for example code.

Comment: With an unregister method I could change the authorizationStatus to NotDetermined or Restricted and check it later before start to startUpdatingLocation. As I can't do this, I have to store the user information in a app variable. Ok, this is really easy, and I already did, but as I can keep the user preferences (register/unregister) for Push Notifications, I thought that I could do the same for Location. Thanks for the comment.